# check if a number is triangular

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to figure out of a number is triangular so I started writing my logical train of thought and ran into a little problem with my code I get an error that states "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" any help is most appreciated.
here is what my code looks like that is causing this issue:

```
x = int(input("Please enter an int: "))
i = x(x+1)/2
l = []
l.append(i)
print(i)
```

Comment: You need to have `x*(x+1)` instead of `x(x+1)`

Comment: `i = x(x+1)/2` should be `i = x*(x+1)/2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `x(x+1)/2`, what do you expect this to mean? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel was trying to multiply x by x+1 / 2. i believe John and Ben have solved my dilemma, thank you for the warm welcome.

Comment: @serge By the way, `y` is a triangular number if and only if `1 + 8*y` is a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `*` operator for multiplication.

```py
x = int(input("Please enter an int: "))
i = x*(x+1)/2 # << fixed here
l = []
l.append(i)
print(i)
```